# How to correctly handle nested exception inside catch block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I have the following piece of code, and I'm trying to understand how can I correctly handle exception in catch block so both exceptions (`mainException` and `anotherException`) are thrown so in case of `anotherException` we do not lose info from `mainException`.
Also code smells bad - is this kind of try-catch usage is some kind of anti-pattern? Is there a better/correct way to handle this kind of situations?

```
        try {
            -some code-
        } catch (RuntimeException mainException) {
            try {
                -another code-
            } catch (Exception anotherException) {
                throw anotherException;
            } finally {
                throw mainException;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java 7, as part of the work on *try-with-resources*, the [`Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) class was extended with support for [suppressed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-) exceptions, specifically intended for scenarios like this.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException("Foo");
    } catch (RuntimeException mainException) {
        try {
            throw new Exception("Bar");
        } catch (Exception anotherException) {
            mainException.addSuppressed(anotherException);
        }
        throw mainException;
    }
}
```

*Output (stacktrace)*

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Foo
    at Test.main(Test.java:5)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: Bar
        at Test.main(Test.java:8)
```